# Firefox does not accept that session variable is unset, while Chrome does

Tags: php, session, session-variables

In my `index.php` I am including checkUser.php with the following code:

```
<?php

session_start();
echo("DEBUG_checkUser:" . $_SESSION['name'] . "<br>");
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    header('Location: denied.php');
} else {
    echo("<span style='font-size: 12px'>Logged in as " . $_SESSION['fname'] . " " . $_SESSION['lname'] . " (" . $_SESSION['name'] . "). ");
    echo("<a href='../POC/logoff.php'>Logoff</a>.");
    echo("</span>");
}
?>
```

Then I have `logoff.php` with the following code:

```
<?php

session_start();
unset($_SESSION['name']);
//echo("DEBUG" . $_SESSION['name'] . "<br>"); //Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\POC\logoff.php on line 5
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../POC/index.php');
?>
```

My expectation is, that by clicking Logoff, `$_SESSION['name']` will be unset, and the user will be redirected from `index.php` to `denied.php`. This works as expected in Chrome (103.0.5060.114), but not in Firefox (103.0b9).
Functions `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()` are redundant IMO (indeed in Chrome it works without), I just added them to avoid getting answers, that I should add them.
If I comment out redirection to `index.php` and uncomment the display of `$_SESSION['name']`, I get an error for undefined index, so the session variable is correctly unset, but why Firefox does not accept that after redirection to `index.php`? And `$_SESSION['name']`, even though correctly unset in `logoff.php`, displays existing name, as the unsetting were not taking place.
I deleted all cookies for `'localhost'` which I am using.
Cookie PHPSESSID is the same before and after logoff.
What should I do so this would also work in Firefox?

**EDIT**:
It was a cache issue, I set this to 0 seconds in `.htaccess` file and now everything works in both browsers:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

So the question would be ... why did this work in Chrome before, when the cache for php was set to 60 seconds?

Comment: The only connection between the browser and the server regarding sessions is the session-cookie. Check the name of the session-cookie before and after logoff. Maybe Firefox is using different session id's?

Comment: try using following session_start();
$_SESSION = array(); // destroy all $_SESSION data
setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", time() - 3600, "/");
session_destroy();

Comment: Regenerate id function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: @Michel;PHPSESSID is the same before and after logoff

Comment: @AqibJaved; nothing of that worked.

Comment: @MisterG13; regenerate Id also didn't work (or I didn't used it correctly).

Comment: Change to unset($_session) this will clear entire array. And my preference is to use logout as a function, not another page (eliminate the extra session start). You're code should work as it's listed. Browser cache should not be an issue for the code shown.

Comment: Fyi using isset can create a false positive. $variable = "" is considered "set" or true. Switch to empty()

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference what browser you are using, the session is server-side. I think this is a browser cache situation. Open the Developer Tools in Firefox and disable the cache on the Network tab ([see where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49ero.png)).

Comment: Indeed that worked ... Can I enforce from php that cache would be disabled (for one page), so this will work in all browsers?